# Manual commit in @KafkaHandler (spring-kafka)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am consuming Kafka events using @KafkaHandler on the method level (@KafkaListener on class level).

I have seen a lot of examples where an "Acknowledgement" argument is available, on which the "acknowledge()" method can be called to commit consumption of the event, however, I am not able to get the acknowledgement object populated when including it as an argument to my method. How do I manual commit when using a KafkaHandler? Is it possible at all?

Code example:

```
@Service
@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic", groupId = "mygroup")
public class TestListener {

@KafkaHandler
public void consumeEvent(MyEvent event, Acknowledgement ack) throws Exception {
    //... processing
    ack.acknowledge(); // ack is not available
}
```

Using SpringBoot and Spring-kafka.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the listener container with `AckMode.MANUAL` or `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` to get this functionality.

However, it's generally better to let the container take care of committing the offset with `AckMode.RECORD` or `AckMode.BATCH` (default).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#committing-offsets

**EDIT**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So68844554Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So68844554Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so68844554").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}

@Component
@KafkaListener(id =  "so68844554", topics = "so68844554")
class Foo {

    @KafkaHandler
    void listen(String in, Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println(in);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

}
```

```
% kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe -group so68844554

Consumer group 'so68844554' has no active members.

GROUP           TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
so68844554      so68844554      0          2               2               0               -               -               -
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already configured ackmode manual and have verified that events are not ACK:ed. Still, the Acknowledgement argument is not populated

Comment: I just tested it without any problems; see the edit; if you still can't figure it out, post a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior you are seeing.